# Can is share Keychain items ios app and watch app

Tags: ios, watchkit, keychain

I am doing a watch app with the iOS companion app, and I need to share access tokens stored in key chains on the iOS app. Is this something that can be done?

I am using https://github.com/square/Valet, and from their documentation, it looks like it can be done. I tried every way, but I still i can't read the keychain items.

I tried app groups and keychain groups.

Comment: Only if the user has iCloud keychain enabled and you allow the keychain item to sync though iCloud. It would be simpler for your iOS app to provide the token to your watch app via a WCSession and for the watch app to store the token in the watch keychain directly